# Appkey is not entitled to use the Message Center in Urbanairship

Tags: php, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I have created development app in urbanairship and trying to send push notification from server using PHP code.

My code:

```
        define('APPKEY','xxx'); // Your App Key
        define('PUSHSECRET', 'ytyy'); // Your Master Secret
        define('PUSHURL', 'https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/');
        $notification = array();
        $notification['alert'] = "alert";
        $platform = array();
        array_push($platform, "android"); //comment out if you don't want Android
        $richpush = array();
        $richpush['title'] = "title";
        $richpush['body'] = $message;


        if(strlen($deviceToken)>50){
            $deviceToken=str_replace(" ","",$deviceToken);
            $push = array("audience"=>array("device_token"=>$deviceToken), "notification"=>$notification, "device_types"=>$platform, "message"=>$richpush);
        }else{
            $deviceToken=str_replace(" ","-",$deviceToken);
            $push = array("audience"=>array("apid"=>$deviceToken),              "notification"=>$notification, "device_types"=>$platform, "message"=>$richpush);
        }

        $json = json_encode($push);


        $session = curl_init(PUSHURL);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, APPKEY . ':' . PUSHSECRET);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, True);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, False);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;'));
        $content = curl_exec($session);
        echo "Response: " . $content . "\n";
```

But I'm getting :

```
Response: {"ok":false,"error":"The specified appkey [xxx] is not entitled to use the Message Center.","error_code":403}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message Center is not included in the Start or Basic accounts. Contact [support](https://support.urbanairship.com/home) and they will work with you to add Message Center entitlements.

Comment: Is Message Center required to be able to send push notifications from server integration? I cannot find a clear answer for this question.

Comment: No, message center is only required to send message center messages. Push notifications can be sent with or without a message center message.